# Permission is only granted to system apps in Android Manifest

Tags: html

While i am inserting this permission in manifest it shows error " Permission is only granted to system apps"

Actually i used this permission for developing application based on Oauth2 token. But i cant enable this permission. Can any Help me?

Comment: Which permission are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission is granted to system apps only.

For your information, there are 2 types of Android apps: system & user

> **User apps** are just all your normal app installations through the Google Play Store, Amazon Appstore or sideloading. These go into the
>   /data partition of your Android phone, which is the part of the
>   internal memory made available for user data and apps.
>
> **System apps** are basically the apps that come pre-installed with your ROM. In a standard Android user environment, the user doesn’t
>   have write access to the /system partition and thus, installing or
>   uninstalling system apps directly isn’t possible.
>
> In order to install an app as a system app on your Android device,
>   **your device must either be rooted or have a custom recovery installed (or both).**

That being said, that error is actually wrong because you have a valid code and compilation should work. It would be better if it gave a warning instead. In Eclipse you can easily fix it. Just go to:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.
```

Find **ProtectedPermission** from the list and set the severity to something other than error(info for example). This way your project will still compile.