# ACCOUNT_MANAGER - "Permission is only granted to system apps"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following the instructions found [here at android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html). These instructions say to add these two lines of code into the manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

**The problem is that I now get an error on the "ACCOUNT_MANAGER" line saying "Permission is only granted to system apps".**

**My application is not going to be a system application** and I need to authenticate to OAuth2 services. How can it be possible that ANY app that uses OAuth2 needs to be a system application?

**Does anyone know how to use ACCOUNT_MANAGER without requiring my application to be a "system application"?**

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597125/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app-in-manifest) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601819/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-apps-in-android-manifest). They say that, for the permissions they have listed, the error is a "fake" error message. Does anyone know if the 'ACCOUNT_MANAGER error is a fake message? Can I tell the compiler to ignore this like the suggestions in these other posts?

Comment: In new version of android use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission . Try it

Comment: Can you tell us for what you need OAuth2? Mostly, you can use something like Google Sign In API if you need it for authenticating users from their existing account

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCOUNT_MANAGER)

> String ACCOUNT_MANAGER
>
> Allows applications to call into AccountAuthenticators.
>
> Not for use by third-party applications.

ACCOUNT_MANAGER permission can only be granted to system app

If your app requires AccountManager, you can create an AccountAuthenticator service like in this [tutorial](https://www.pilanites.com/android-account-manager/)

Or you can request MANAGE_ACCOUNTS permission as explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44293/what-does-permission-manage-accounts-mean/44295#44295)

> MANAGE_ACCOUNTS: The API documentation is not that clear about this
>   permission. But according to Bryans answer, an app can only
>   delete/modify an account it created itself. Of course it can create
>   any new account, and manage that.